# Add where clause to Doctrine native query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to add where clause to Native Query in Symfony Doctrine. For example, my initial query like:

```
      $query = $em->createQuery("select distinct s.id
    from service s join tags_services t on t.service_id=s.id join tag on t.tag_id = tag.id
    where
        (s.title like '%play%'
        or tag.name like '%play%'
        or s.description  like '%play%')
    order by 
         s.title like '%play%' desc,
         tag.name like '%play%' desc,
         s.description  like '%play%' desc");
     $services = $query->getResult();
```

but if I want to filter this result with more parameters, like adding

```
 'AND s.category = :category'
```

if category is given. or add sort parameter. Basically I am trying to understand how I can change this query string dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
$filter = '';

if (category instanceOf Category) {
   filter = ' AND s.category = :category'
}

$sql = '
    select distinct s.id
     from service s 
     join tags_services t on t.service_id=s.id join tag on t.tag_id = tag.id
     where
         (s.title like :play
         or tag.name like :play
         or s.description  like :play)
         '. $filter .'
     order by 
         s.title desc,
         tag.name desc,
         s.description desc'
```

You can also do it with querybuilder :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->addSelect('distinct s.id')
    ->join('s.tags_services', 'ts')
    ->join('ts.tag', 't');

$qb->where($qb->expr()->orX(
    $qb->expr()->like('s.title', ':play'),
    $qb->expr()->like('t.name', ':play'),
    $qb->expr()->like('s.description', ':play'),
));

if (category instanceOf Category) {
    $qb->addWhere(...)
}
```

Comment: The key part here is this part: `order by  s.title like '%play%' desc,
         tag.name like '%play%' desc,
         s.description  like '%play%' desc` how can i have this in QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Choose between two options:
1- Divide your sql in two sections to add at the end of the fisrt part the optional parameters:

```
    $query = "SELECT distinct s.id
        from service s 
        join tags_services t on t.service_id=s.id
        join tag on t.tag_id = tag.id
        where
            (s.title like '%play%'
            or tag.name like '%play%'
            or s.description  like '%play%')"
    ;
    if ($category !== null){
        $query .=  " AND s.category = ".$category. " ";
    }
    $query .=  "order by s.id  desc";
    $em->createQuery($query);
    $services = $query->getResult();
```

2- Write only "where 1 = 1" and depending on the clauses add more conditions. This one is very useful because you can add as much as you want dinamically or none:

```
    $query = "SELECT distinct s.id
        FROM service s
        JOIN tags_services t ON t.service_id=s.id
        JOIN tag on t.tag_id = tag.id
        WHERE
            1 = 1 "
    ;
    if ($name !== null){
        $query .= " AND tag.name LIKE '%".$name.".%' ";
    }
    if ($category !== null){
        $query .=  " AND s.category = ".$category. " ";
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY s.id DESC";
    $em->createQuery($query);
    $services = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: PS. For your " how can i have this in QueryBuilder?" question, do this:

`$qb->orderBy('s.title', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('tag.name ', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('s.description  ', 'DESC')
;`